# case statementing on particular items

Tags: sql

I am unable to run a query which looks like this

```
select item(id),case statement (on that particular item )
from table( which contains n no. of items)
```

It should return each `id` and case statement of that particular `id`

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your effort, table structures and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of the `CASE` statement in most RDBMS:

```
SELECT
    id,
    -- Usage one
    CASE [fieldToCheck]
        WHEN [value1] THEN [result if the field equals to value1]
        WHEN [value2] THEN [result if the field equals to value2]
        ELSE [If all the above was false]
    END AS [alias]

    -- Usage two
    CASE
        WHEN fieldToCheck = [value1] THEN [result if the condition is true]
        WHEN fieldToCheck = [value2] THEN [result if the condition is true]
        WHEN fieldToCheck = [value3] THEN [result if the condition is true]
        WHEN fieldToCheck = [value4] OR anotherField = [anotherValue] THEN [result if the condition is true]
        ELSE [If all the above was false]
    END
FROM
    [table]
```

Please note that if two conditions (in one `CASE` statement) are true, only the first one will be used!

Comment: Oh, and please check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask